# VMWARE Network Configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

and thank your help in advance.

I am trying to setup a virtual environment in which i need to create 5 virtual machines running ubuntu and i need them to be able to see each other in the network as well a able to connect to the internet... i try using the vmnet1 adapter which allows me to see all the machines but so far i've failed to configure the VMs to be able to access the internet.

FYI. I am trying to setup a 5 VM hadoop cluster for self study...

Comment: Do you have NAT enabled on the virtual machines?

Comment: Thank you, i just make the configuration changes and test it is working great... :)